# reposition a marker when I press button android API V2

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I have the following code and, when I press a menu button I would like to reposition the same marker and the camera but I do not have idea how to do it, I've read oficial documentation but I haven't found info. I'm using `repositionMarker()` method to do it, but Im not sure what to do. Thanks

```
public class Init extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
{
   private MapFragment map;
   static final LatLng PERTH = new LatLng(19.0436, -98.1981);
   private CameraUpdate camaraloc, camaraloczoom;
   private Marker markerloc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);
                map = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (map != null)
        {
           map.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map)
    {
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        camaraloc = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(PERTH);
        camaraloczoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(8);
        map.moveCamera(camaraloc);
        map.animateCamera(camaraloczoom);
        markerloc = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(PERTH)
            .title("city").snippet("esp").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_inicio, menu);
            return true;
           return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Toast.makeText(this, "name marker: "+markerloc.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                reposicionMarker();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void repositionMarker()
    {
         camaraloc = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(16.65, -91.8658));
         camaraloczoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);
        if ( markerloc != null )
            markerloc.remove();
        markerloc.setPosition(new LatLng(16.65, -91.8658));
        // here is where I dont know what to do
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setLocation` on the `Marker` should work, for changing its location. What seems to be your problem is that you are actually removing the marker right before you set the new location.